# Manually Start a Systemctl Script After Boot Up

Tags: boot, 20.04

Using Ubuntu 20.04
I'm trying to start a systemctl script (ModemManager) but I want to start it up only when I'm at the desktop.
I currently use:

```
 systemctl enable ModemManager.service
 systemctl start ModemManager.service
```

The problem with just using these is that I have to disable and stop the service before shutdown or else it's going to boot up as enabled by default.

Is there any way to bypass the disabling part?

Comment: You don't *have* to enable the service to start the service, enable and disable determines autostart but you can still manually start the service.  Have you tried `sudo systemctl disable ModemManager.service`, then done `sudo systemctl start ModemManager.service` and then rebooted and seen if Modem Manager actually loads on reboot?  It shouldn't since the service is disabled (but was *manually* - not automatically - started)

Comment: Thanks, I did try this but ModemManager.service doesn't seem to do anything but I think this may just be this specific service file